# Bundle arguments with R.id.[attribute]

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to send integers from 7 different fragments to an 8th fragment that will be sent to an SQLite database. Currently though, I can't get anything to send to another fragment.

MiscTab.java

```
package com.example.test.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class MiscTab extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MiscTab";
    private View root;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Find the root view, and put in into a variable for later use by other functions
        this.root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.misc_tab, container, false); //creates this.setupButton(R.id.misc_dead_bot_int, R.id.misc_dead_bot_plus, 0, 1, 1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_dead_bot_int, R.id.misc_dead_bot_minus, 0, 1, -1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_disabled_bot_int, R.id.misc_disabled_bot_plus, 0, 1, 1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_disabled_bot_int, R.id.misc_disabled_bot_minus, 0, 1, -1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_tipped_bot_int, R.id.misc_tipped_bot_plus, 0, 1, 1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_tipped_bot_int, R.id.misc_tipped_bot_minus, 0, 1, -1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_didnt_show_int, R.id.misc_didnt_show_plus, 0, 1, 1);
        this.setupButton(R.id.misc_didnt_show_int, R.id.misc_didnt_show_minus, 0, 1, -1);
        return this.root;
    }

    private void setupButton(int textID, int buttonID, final int minimum, final int maximum, final int stepValue) {
        // Find the button from the view
        Button button = this.root.findViewById(
        // Find the buttons textview from the view
        final TextView text = this.root.findViewById(
        // Set the buttons actions to increase the count by the step value
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View 
                // Find the text views current value. If there is an error, assume 0
                int initialCount;
                try {
                    initialCount = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    initialCount = 0;
                }
                // Calculate the final count value
                int finalCount = initialCount + stepValue;
                // Check if it matches the bounds
                if (finalCount > maximum) {
                    finalCount = maximum;
                }
                if (finalCount < minimum) {
                    finalCount = minimum;
                }
                // Update the text to display the new final count
                text.setText(String.valueOf(finalCount));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Relevant code in my MainActivity.java

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putInt(MiscTab.misc_dead_bot_int);
```

When I try to pass `MiscTab.misc_dead_bot_int` to the arguments for putInt, it tells me it can't resolve it. Im assuming it's because it's not initialized anywhere, instead just following the string in the XML. I'm not sure what I can do to get these values into a sendable format. I tried sending it to a string, but the only output value I got was a large number instead.

Comment: Alright, will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question. You are trying to retrieve this (MiscTab.misc_dead_bot_int) value from a fragment, right? Anyways, Your above example of Bundle has the wrong parameter. Make sure that you are passing correctly. The bundle function putInt have two parameters which are key-value pares. I think you missed a key. Try as follows

In your Main Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(YOUR_KEY, MiscTab.misc_dead_bot_int);
```

And In your Fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int misc_dead_bot_int = getArguments().getInt(YOUR_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to receive MiscTab.misc_dead_bot_int from the fragment. I'm sorry for not being clearer.  

I knew I was missing a parameter, but not that I was thinking of it backwards. Both the MiscTab.misc_dead_bot_int and the key now give me the "Can't resolve symbol" in both the MainAcitivty, and the fragment though, so im not sure whats wrong still.